# Facebook checkin FQL query

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this multiquery to query Facebook FQL in order to get all the Checkins made near my location at the last week..

The Wierd thing is that Facebook response back with checkins made by author_uid which are not my friends (thought he will automatically wont allow me to see that data to keep those people privacy) which is not really helping me..

My goal is to get all the checkins in my area for all my friends.

My biggest problem is that when you have many friends - to get all their checkins is a mission impossible - because when using the

```
SELECT page_id, coords, author_uid, timestamp,message FROM checkin WHERE author_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 = me())
```

is a query never ended... or at least i wasn't patient to wait long enough..

this is my current query:

```
{"checkin":"SELECT page_id, coords, author_uid, timestamp,message FROM checkin WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #places) AND timestamp >= 1358499380",
"places":"SELECT page_id, name, distance(latitude, longitude, '32.804752175000004', '34.980942025') FROM place WHERE checkin_count > 50 AND distance(latitude, longitude, '32.804752175000004', '34.980942025') <= 50000 LIMIT 50"}
```

will be thanks full for suggestions..

Comment: Why not add a limit and offset to the query? Like this perhaps: `SELECT page_id, coords, author_uid, timestamp, message FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 = me()) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0`. You can always _page_ in more data this way without burdening your app.

Comment: what does the offset means ?

Comment: Not sure if I can explain this right. Let me try this with an example. With the query in my earlier comment, the result is a break up of the first 10 of the entire result set. For the next set of data, you would use, say, LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10. This will now give you results _10 through 20_. Next, `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20`, will give you results _20 through 30_.... Hopefully this will give you an idea. ;-)

Comment: The problem with your multi-query is what you have already observed. Your query is generic and does not have the filter to separate out your friends from all other FB users. I am thinking, your first query with LIMIT and OFFSET parameters will do the job for you.

Comment: but yet, when trying to run your query - it is still endless...
the real problem is that i can't use SQL JOIN... it really limits you with the current FQL